# animation two objects with different velocity

Tags: python, tkinter

This script show movement two squares with the same velocity. How do I set different velocity? Thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

rc1 = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 260, 120, 360, outline='white', fill='blue')
rc2 = canvas.create_rectangle(20, 20, 120, 120, outline='white', fill='red')

for x in range(100):
    y = 0
    x = 5
    time.sleep(0.2)
    canvas.move(rc1, x, y)
    canvas.move(rc2, x, y)
    canvas.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use the same velocity for the two move commands.  Where are you stuck on this?

Answer (score 1):

Remember from your physics classes, `v = dx/dt`:

velocity = change in position / change in time

Apply that here. The change in time is specified here by `time.sleep(0.2)` - 1/5 of a second. You probably don't want to change that, so the other thing you can change to modify the velocity is the *change in position* for each timeslice.

Here's where `canvas.move()` comes in - this is the change in position. You're calling it twice in your script, once for `rc1` and once for `rc2`, and both times with the same `x` and `y`. Since the change in position is the same, and the change in time is the same, `rc1` and `rc2` will move at the same rate.

The solution? Just use different variables. Say we want `rc2` to move twice as fast as `rc1` in the same direction:

```
canvas.move(rc1, x, y)
canvas.move(rc2, 2*x, 2*y)
```

Or say we want `rc1` to move along the `x` axis whereas we want `rc2` to move the same distance but along the `y` axis instead:

```
canvas.move(rc1, x, y)
canvas.move(rc2, y, x)
```

Or we want them to move in entirely different trajectories and speeds:

```
x1, y1 = 5, 0
x2, y2 = -13, 7
canvas.move(rc1, x1, y1)
canvas.move(rc2, y2, x2)
```

This last solution is the most flexible, and is what you should probably rely on.